# Button to view in full screen

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing a shiny app with highcharter.

In my app I would like to add an independant button to view my chart in full screen.

I think I have to add JS code with the button "action_fs" in my example...
Here's my app:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    actionButton("mybutton","launch"),
    br(),
    column(width = 6,
           uiOutput("button_fullscreen"),
           highchartOutput("mygraph")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {

  mytab <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mystat=sum(Petal.Length,na.rm = T))

  observeEvent(input$mybutton, {

    output$button_fullscreen <- renderUI({
      actionButton("action_fs","view in full screen")
    })

    output$mygraph <- renderHighchart({
      highchart() %>%
        hc_chart(type = "bar") %>%
        hc_add_series(data = mytab$mystat, name = "Petal.Length") %>%
        hc_xAxis(categories = mytab$Species)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't install `highcharter` (dependency `quantmod` not available), so here is an example with a `ggplot`:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

js <- "
function openFullscreen(elem) {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 3,
      actionButton(
        "fs", "Full screen", 
        onclick = "openFullscreen(document.getElementById('graphContainer'));"
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 9,
      div(
        id = "graphContainer",
        plotOutput("ggplot")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["ggplot"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## EDIT

The problem with the above solution is that the plot height does not change when the app is in full screen mode. With the solution below, the plot height becomes the screen height when one switches to the full screen mode.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

js <- "
function openFullscreen(elem) {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}"

css <- "
#ggplot:-webkit-full-screen {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#ggplot:-ms-fullscreen {
  height: 100%;
}
#ggplot:fullscreen {
  height: 100%;
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 3,
      actionButton(
        "fs", "Full screen", 
        onclick = "openFullscreen(document.getElementById('ggplot'));"
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 9,
      plotOutput("ggplot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["ggplot"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! In my case, when I press the "fullscreen" button the graphic appears on half of the page (and in black with "highcharter")

Comment: @DamienDotta See my edit. Do you get the full height with this solution ?

Comment: maybe do you have a solution to fix my background's color that goes black in full screen ? I tried something like this but it doesn't work : ```background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);```

Comment: @DamienDotta I can't see the rendering with `highcharter` because I'm not able to install this package. With my `ggplot` example there's no problem with the background color, since the plot takes all the available space, so there's no background. It is not the case with `highcharter`?

Comment: Ok never mind ! my background's color is black in full screen https://pasteboard.co/J3ausBN.png

Comment: my graph is displayed normally here : https://pasteboard.co/J3avyEPV.png

Comment: @DamienDotta I've managed to install `highcharter` now :) For the background color, add `%>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme(chart = list(backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF")))` in `renderHighchart`. By default, this color is transparent; that's why you get white in the app and black in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Impressive i hadn't thought about it! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

The [shinyfullscreen](https://github.com/etiennebacher/shinyfullscreen) package offers a very simple solution to this problem. It was recently [updated](https://github.com/etiennebacher/shinyfullscreen/issues/5) to include a full screen button that can work on individual charts or make your entire Shiny App full screen.

You can install the development version by running the code below:

```
devtools::install_github("etiennebacher/shinyfullscreen")
```